# Is this the right approach to use custom annotation in guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Hi I have a custom annotation in guice

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE})
public @interface Worker {
    String value();
}
```

```
class WorkerImpl implements Named, Serializable {

  private final String value;

  public WorkerImpl(String value) {
    this.value = checkNotNull(value, "name");
  }

  @Override
  public String value() {
    return this.value;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    // This is specified in java.lang.Annotation.
    return (127 * "value".hashCode()) ^ value.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Worker)) {
      return false;
    }

    Worker other = (Worker) o;
    return value.equals(other.value());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "@" + Worker.class.getName() + "(value=" + Annotations.memberValueString(value) + ")";
  }

  @Override
  public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
    return Worker.class;
  }

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
}
```

Now I define a bunch of classes something like these

```
@Worker("worker1")
class Test1 implements Base {
}

@Worker("worker2")
class Test2 implements Base {
}
```

Now if the define the bindings in guice like

```
bind(Base.class)
    .annotatedWith(Test1.class.getAnnotation(Worker.class))
    .to(Test1.class);

bind(Base.class)
    .annotatedWith(Test2.class.getAnnotation(Worker.class))
    .to(Tes2.class);
```

And if I try to get the corresponding instances from the injector like

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(Worker.class, new WorkerImpl("worker1")));
injector.getInstance(Key.get(Worker.class, new WorkerImpl("worker2")));
```

Will these give me instances of worker1 and worker2??

I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom annotation, you should implement it correctly.

For instance, you have the `@Worker` annotation but `WorkerImpl` implements `@Named`. You should make it implement `@Worker`.

Now, your bindings should look like this instead:

```
bind(Base.class)
  .annotatedWith(new WorkerImpl("worker1"))
  .to(Test1.class);
bind(Base.class)
  .annotatedWith(new WorkerImpl("worker2"))
  .to(Test2.class);
```

And you'll get the instances like this:

```
Base test1 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(Base.class, new WorkerImpl("worker1")));
Base test2 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(Base.class, new WorkerImpl("worker2")));
```

For the rest, you correctly handle the Annotation hashCode, which is the hardest part of creating custom annotation implementations.